# write a simple program in python about sum in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program to give some number for user then if sum of 3 number in list == 0 prit yes:
part of my code:

```
import os
from typing import Mapping
from colorama import Fore , init
init()
os.system("cls" or "clear")
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

# GIVE LIST NUMBER
listed = input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A List Of Number: ")
# CONVERT INPUT(STR) TO LIST:
listed = list(map(int, listed.split(',')))
listed= list(map(int, listed))
#CHEACK SUM IN LIST == 0
```

I don't know how check my IF to Print yes or no.....

Example:

list = [3 , 2 , -2 , -5]

print YES as 3+2-5 = 0

Comment: sum of list = [3 , 2 , -2 , -5] is 0 ? how ? 3+2-2-5 = -2

Comment: oh i guess i understood what you mean

Comment: no dude just 3 itme of list sum together no all of them

Comment: so please tell me if you know the answer

Comment: check my update and notify me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I guess you want something like this:**

```
import os
from typing import Mapping
from colorama import Fore , init
init()
os.system("cls" or "clear")
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

# GIVE LIST NUMBER
listed = input(Fore.GREEN+"Please Enter A List Of Number: ")
# CONVERT INPUT(STR) TO LIST:
listed = list(map(int, listed.split(',')))
listed= list(map(int, listed))
#CHEACK SUM IN LIST == 0

if sum(listed) == 0:
    print("yes")
```

**Updated (from your comment):**

```
from itertools import combinations

list1 = [3, 2]
list2 = [3, 2, -2, -5]
list3 = [5, -5, 0]


def check_sum(list_of_numbers):
    if len(list_of_numbers) >= 3:
        subsets = list(combinations(list_of_numbers, 3))
        for each_subset in subsets:
            if sum(each_subset) == 0:
                return "Yes"
        return "No"
    else:
        return "No"


print(check_sum(list1))
print(check_sum(list2))
print(check_sum(list3))
```

**Output:**

```
No
Yes
Yes
```

Some credits to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-get-all-subsets-of-given-size-of-a-set/

Comment: user add more than 3 item to list for example: 3,2,2,-5    ||| it's work for 3 items|||| i wrot an example in my quesion

Comment: TNX DUDE u really help me , i have only 2 Question to finish my homework , anyway thank you

Comment: @m7.arman: YW; Do you free on using modules ? or you should write each function from scratch ? because as you can see i used itertools, its standard and default python library.

Comment: @m7.arman: would you upvote my answer too :)

Comment: I think have no problem to use modules

Comment: @m7.arman: i answerd your other question check that too

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) like so:

`total = sum(map(int, listed.split(',')))`

Answer (score 0):

```
listed=[3,5,3]

if sum(listed)==0:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: A code-only answer has no value, and that's right everytime

Comment: user add more than 3 item to list for example: 3,2,2,-5    ||| it's work for 3 items|||| i wrot an example in my quesion